# How to copy N words under cursor and to right of cursor?

Tags: gvim, cut-copy-paste, vi-words

How can I copy **continue close current** into buffer without getting into visual mode?

[image]

That is, how to copy N words from cursor?

Comment: Ok I just learned about v3w. That works..

Comment: `y3e` if at the start of the word, else `viw2ey`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `y3w` if you are at beginning of a word (so: yank 3 words) or `by3w` to get at the beginning of the word first (so: back yank 3 words)